# Replacing a string in java

Tags: java

I am trying to replace the short form words to normal from a string in java but don't know how to do it in a good way because I can have multiple ('ve 're 'nt) and such. Is it good to use array list and if so how do I achieve that?

What I have tried so far:

```
public class main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "We've been doing this for ages. I'm having a difficulty doing this. Thats getting confusing.";
  s = s.replaceAll("we've", "we have");
  s = s.replaceAll("I'm", "I am");
  s = s.replaceAll("that's", "that is");

 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt? Note that you can chain those calls if you want to.

Comment: e.g., `s = s.replaceAll("we've", "we have").replaceAll("I'm, "I am").replaceAll("that's, "that is");`

Comment: Why not just `replaceAll("'ve", " have")` so you don't have to define different replacement calls for "we've", "you've", "they've" etc. pp.

Comment: Aha, so my question is If I have a huge list of things that want's to get replaced which are more than 200. Do I use an array and run a for loop that checks if the first word from a string is equal to any from the list? If so then replace it with something from the other replacement list? After that, I go to the next word from the string or what is another better way to handle it?

Comment: You miss quotation mark " char at the end of some string, so your code does not compile.

Comment: @skitzo143 having two lists for that is just bad design. Use a Map where the key is what you want to replace and the value the replacement. Then you can just iterate over the Map entries and do you business. Or alternativly create your own class with the two values (The thing to replace and the replacement) and have a List of that custom class objects.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS It won't work because it checks for a word and 've is a text that the word contains.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS According to your first comment, note that OP should be careful when using this shortcut with "`''s`" - e. g. in sentences like "`This is John's pen`"

Comment: If anyone could post the code I will be so glad.

Comment: i do not think that you can solve a **grammatical problem** with simple replacements, if you want to do it **properly**. (Stackoverflow solves coding problem - not grammar problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Map<String, String>`, for example a HashMap where the keys would be the short form to replace and the value the replacement string. Then you could just iterate `Map.entrySet()` and call the `replace` method on the string.

Code could be (please note that I have omitted the initial letter - except for I which has to be upper case - to avoid the capitalized problem):

```
    String str = s;
    HashMap<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    replacements.put("e've", "e have");
    replacements.put("I'm", "I am");
    replacements.put("hat's", "hat is");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: replacements.entrySet()) {
        str = str.replaceAll(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

It does not really make sense if it is intended to be used only once, but it could be the base of a method that could be re-used on many strings.

Comment: Thanks so much <3 I am using it in a simple chatbot so I will have multiple strings :P

Comment: If your text has many possible replacements, `str = str.replaceAll` would be performance loss. `StringBuilder` your right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more efficiently using regexes.

First, build a map containing your searches and replacements.

```
Map<String, String> replacements =
    Map.of("we've", "we have", "I'm", "I am" /* etc */);
```

(or some pre-Java 9 equivalent)

Now, build a regex to match the things you want to replace:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    replacements.keySet()
        .stream()
        .map(Pattern::quote)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
```

Now, create a Matcher and a StringBuilder in which to accumulate your new string:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
  String replacement = replacements.get(m.group(0));
  m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String newS = sb.toString();
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rXMYo6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` if you don't want to keep creating new strings all the time:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("We've been doing this for ages. I'm having a difficulty doing this. That's getting confusing.");
    HashMap<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    replacements.put("'ve", " have");
    replacements.put("'m", " am");
    replacements.put("'s", " is");
    // others...
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: replacements.entrySet()) {
        int index;
        while ((index = builder.indexOf(entry.getKey())) != -1) {
            builder.replace(index, index + entry.getKey().length(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
```

Do note that if you are trying to replace all contractions like this, you are unlikely going to succeed 100% as some phrases contract to the same contraction, for example:

> That has -> That's
>   That is -> That's

Also note that some `'`s don't indicate a contraction:

> Mary's <-- how are you handling this?

You can kind of tackle the second problem by looking for more specific sequences like `That's` instead of just `'s`, but for the first problem, you will need to somehow understand the context.

Comment: I am using a chatbot where I keep getting messages so I don't need a string builder but thanks ;)